# How to send and recive text in windows phone using silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone

I want to send a message from a windows phone to other windows phone via web services.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [Push Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). They are used to initiate an activity on a phone from a third party. There are three types of them: Tile Notification, Toast Notification and Raw Notification.

Toast Notifications (Example: SMS alert) are received when the application is not running. If for some reason sending from one phone to another implies that both of them run at the same time, consider using Raw Notifications. However, I suppose you should use both of them: if a Raw Notification is dropped (this usually means that the application is not running in the foreground), send Toast Notification.

As far as I undestand your requirements, you should do the following:

1. Once the application is started (or a user is logged in), establish Push channel and request PushUri for the phone from Microsoft Push Notification Server
2. Send the PushUri to your service, associate it with the user and save it.
3. To send a message to a phone application, just pass appropriate parameters to its PushUri. You can do this either from your web service or directly from another phone.

You may find the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402537%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) useful. There are examples of how to establish, send and receive them.

P.S.  Take into account that the second Toast Notification may fail as well because during the timespan between two Notifications the user may launch your application. Don't forget to handle this.